# GridView item text wrapping

Tags: gridview, word-wrap

I have a GridView control that I am dynamically creating at runtime. I am creating all the columns like this.

```
foreach (GridColumnConfig column in columns)
{
    BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
    boundField.HeaderText = column.Title;
    boundField.DataField = column.FieldName;
    boundField.SortExpression = column.FieldName;
    boundField.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
    boundField.ItemStyle.Width = new Unit(column.Width, UnitType.Pixel);
    boundField.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = TextToAlign(column.Align);
    m_GenericListView.Grid.Columns.Add(boundField);        
}
```

However even though I have specified the item not to wrap text it still does so in IE6. In FireFox it just creates a very wide column which is probably not what either, even though the width has been specified.

Is there any way to really control these widths and wrapping columns in a GridView ?

Answer (score 1):

The word-wrap CSS style works for me when I want to control wrapping.  Here's a discussion that pretty well covers it.

http://bytes.com/forum/thread627827.html

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to the gridview - 
 Style="white-space: nowrap"

Gridview doesnt have a property called style, but you can add it and it will work.

Or you can declare a CSS class and assign it to the gridview